# What's a general term for things that can be shut and locked?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a general term for things that can be shut, and possibly locked. This should cover examples such as -- doors, gates, windows, safes, boxes, and so forth. A usage might be like this example:

> As a spy, Alice was trained to be able to enter through any _____.

Or, a second example:

> Gandalf the wizard's shutting-spell places a magic lock to fasten any _____.

What's the best general term for such door-like impediments?

Note that I am specifically *not* interested in any reference to the lock itself, but rather the thing it is fastening.

Comment: To enter a building? Enter an installation such as a military base?

Comment: 'Lockables' doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You could just use "locks"; "open any locks" should cover most of what you want.

Comment: Doors, gates, and windows seem to be in a different category from boxes, even though its is true that all of them can be said to be shut and locked. Do you really want a word that covers both complete containers and the parts of containers that make them openable/closable?

Comment: Or "able to open anything with a lock". (Excluding wigs and canals.)

Comment: I would say _No lock could resist her._ The reader would understand the meaning you are describing.

Comment: ..................... a case?

Comment: I've clarified that the lock is _not_ the thing of interest here.

Hopefully people will ignore the edit someone else made to the example (since rolled back) that advanced that impression.

Comment: @Graffito strangely that word popped into my mind just before I saw your comment. I had just remarked that my answer doesn't suit the later question edit, but it's worse than that. How can the same word be used in *both* the OP's examples? If Gandalf could lock it, why wouldn't Alice have been able to pass it?

Comment: I know of no such single-word super-class for **door** that would include gates, portcullises, windows, drawbridges, hinged doors, sliding doors, pocket doors, treasure-chest and coffer lids, etc . It would have to be a periphrasis, like **means of access**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not going to find a word that covers both passageways and boxes.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins it's bad form to change the question after answers have been posted. It didn't add clarity, but confusion.

Comment: Simple: *way in.* Magical: *portal* or smth like that.

Comment: @Graffito: "Enclosure" is helpful. That also suggests simply "closure" (which I'm adding as an answer below).

Comment: Perhaps, you shouldn't force a single word and I doubt there is an unambiguous hypernym. You could use "the lockables" as an adjectival noun through zero derivation but it is not that useful and it doesn't fit your examples. You could use a phrase like "lockable item".

Comment: Referring to the possibility of being locked (which entails being shut), the word _lockable_ has been in use for a long time, and indeed is a standard example of structural ambiguity in the two meanings of _unlockable_ -- 'not capable of being locked' vs 'capable of being unlocked'.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is the option of simply using **closure**.

> anything that closes or shuts

(Webster's New World Dictionary, Third College Edition)

Comment: I've decided to use this, as it works well for my use-case. Thanks to @Graffito for suggesting "enclosure" which led in this direction.

Comment: A safe/strong box (which you mentioned in OP) is not a "closure"

Comment: That is not the usual meaning of [closure](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/closure).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Multiple other dictionaries show this sense of the term.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: While it's true that taken literally, this dictionary definition allows this meaning, that isn't actually how English speakers use the word. A closure can be a latch, but not a gate; a zipper but not a jacket; a drawstring but not a bag, and so forth.

Comment: Indeed: the closure is the *fastener*, not the opening.

Answer (score 5):

**Lock.**

> As a spy, Alice was trained to be able to open any **lock**.

Because the tricky part wasn't *opening* the strongbox, vault, door or whatever, but *unlocking* it.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not be the selected answer. See clarification to the question -- and please ignore the edit someone else made that might have given the wrong impression.

Comment: The OP added another example after you answered, which already has the word lock.

Comment: However much this may not be graced with the check mark, it is the right answer. No functional door, window or any other opening is normally stuck in the closed position unless it has a lock on it. To open the ___ (thing that OP asks for), the lock must be opened first. (Source: several years of experience as house framer, and several more as a locksmith)

Comment: @Conrado so how does that work with OP's second example: "Gandalf the wizard's shutting-spell places a magic lock to fasten any lock"? They seem to be looking for a word for an **entrance**, "the thing it is fastening", no matter how many years you have "framed houses".

Comment: @DanielR.Collins In your updated question, I think the problem is to find something that you can both "enter through" and "fasten" and I can't think of anything much better than a "door" or a synonym (gate, portal,...). Could you maybe tell us what exactly you need that word for? Are you writing a story about Alice vs Gandalf?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a change of verb as well:

> ... trained to breach any perimeter: deadbolt, laser security system, or gun tower.

But if you're specifically talking about picking locks, that would be too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Final answer:
A word that works with both of OP's example sentences, and with the broad narrative, is

- [**anything**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anything)

> As a spy, Alice was trained to be able to enter through **anything**.
> Gandalf the wizard's shutting-spell places a magic lock to fasten **anything**.

---

Edit:
Following the OP's question edit about what Gandalf might do, some more offerings.

- **aperture**
- **opening**
- **access**

---

Earlier:

One general term is (from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barrier))

> **barrier**
> <sup>*noun*</sup>
> anything used or acting to block someone from going somewhere or from doing something, or to block something from happening

The example sentence used 'enter', but presumably a spy will be able to leave too, so slightly reworded:

> As a spy, Alice was trained to be able to pass through any barrier.

---

The OP needs Alice to escape from a locked box too, and a broader term could be (also from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obstacle))

> **obstacle**
> <sup>*noun*</sup>
> something that blocks your way so that movement or progress is prevented or made more difficult

> As a spy, Alice was trained to be able to get past any obstacle.

Comment: Unfortunately the subsequent question edit introduces a sentence that [Gandalf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalf) might say, which this answer doesn't fit.

Comment: I am (rather grudgingly) up voting this answer b/c of "opening", which is the closest answer to OP, which asks for a hypernym too broad to be useful. A safe is not an "opening", but an "enclosure". Windows and doors are openings, but only prevent ingress/egress if they have a lock in the closed position.

Comment: @Conrado thanks, my final answer is **anything**. This works with both of the OP's example sentences.

Comment: I think you're too reputable to succumb to "anything"…but I get it.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs the question was too broad. There isn't really a single term that describes the whole range of what was asked. Especially having introduced Gandalf's powers at a late stage.

Comment: I think *access* is it; good answer. One definition: a means of entering or exiting, that's what it means. Otherwise, you're just breaking through or walking under walls, like spy ants or something.

Comment: Was Alice trained to enter through a mouse hole? A grating? A pinhole? I'll bet not, but all of those are 'things' and your sentence says she was.

Comment: @DJClayworth the Alice Liddell character was, and so was Gandalf :)